# Can I take advantage of parallelization to make this piece of code faster?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

OK, a follow-up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23193677/1551513) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23221241/1551513) question. The code I want to modify is of course:

```
function fdtd1d_local(steps, ie = 200)
    ez = zeros(ie + 1);
    hy = zeros(ie);
    for n in 1:steps
        for i in 2:ie
            ez[i]+= (hy[i] - hy[i-1])
        end
        ez[1]= sin(n/10)
        for i in 1:ie
            hy[i]+= (ez[i+1]- ez[i])
        end
    end
    (ez, hy)
end

fdtd1d_local(1);
@time sol1=fdtd1d_local(10);
```

> ```
> elapsed time: 3.4292e-5 seconds (4148 bytes allocated)
> ```

And I've naively tried:

```
function fdtd1d_local_parallel(steps, ie = 200)
    ez = dzeros(ie + 1);
    hy = dzeros(ie);
    for n in 1:steps
        for i in 2:ie
            localpart(ez)[i]+= (hy[i] - hy[i-1])
        end
        localpart(ez)[1]= sin(n/10)
        for i in 1:ie
            localpart(hy)[i]+= (ez[i+1]- ez[i])
        end
    end
    (ez, hy)
end

fdtd1d_local_parallel(1);
@time sol2=fdtd1d_local_parallel(10);
```

> ```
> elapsed time: 0.0418593 seconds (3457828 bytes allocated)
> ```

```
sol2==sol1
```

> ```
> true
> ```

The result is correct, but the performance is much worse. So why? Because parallelization isn't for a dual core old lap-top, or I'm wrong again?

Well, I admit that the only thing I know about parallelization is it can speed up codes but not every piece of code can be paralleled, is there any basic knowledge that one should know before trying parallel programming?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things going on. First, notice the difference in memory consumed. That's a sign that something is wrong. You'll get greater clarity by separating allocation (your `zeros` and `dzeros` lines) from the core algorithm. However, it's unlikely that very much of that memory is being used by allocation; more likely, something in your loop is using memory. Notice that you're describing the `localpart` on the left hand side, but you're using the raw `DArray` on the right hand side. That may be triggering some IPC traffic. If you need to debug the memory consumption, see the ProfileView package.

Second, it's not obvious to me that you're really breaking the problem up among processes. You're looping over each element of the whole array, instead you should have each worker loop over its own piece of the array. However, you're going to run into problems at the edges between localparts, because the updates require the neighboring values. You'd be much better off using a `SharedArray`.

Finally, launching threads has overhead; for small problems, you're better off *not* parallelizing and just using simple algorithms. Only when the computation time gets to hundreds of milliseconds (or more) would I even think about going to the effort to parallelize.

Comment: Well, as mentioned in the question, my second sample is just a naive trial. (I don't understand the somewhat… brief corresponding part of the tutorial very well 囧), and it's a pity that `SharedArray` isn't available for Windows. The sample in the question is in fact a simplified 1D Maxwell's equations solver, when the lists (`ez`, `hy`, and there'll be more in 3D cases) get larger, [it may takes days to compute](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106136/18778).

Answer (score 1):

N.B.:  I'm a relative Julia, FDTD, Maxwell's Equations, and parallel processing noob.

@tholy provided a good answer presenting the important issues to be considered.

In addition, the [Wikipedia Finite-difference time-domain method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-difference_time-domain_method) page presents some good info with references and links to software packages, some of which use some style of parallel processing.

It seems that many parallel processing approaches to FDTD partition the physical environment into smaller chunks and then calculate the chunks in parallel.  One complication is that the boundary conditions must be passed between adjacent chunks.

Using your toy 1D problem, and my limited Julia skills, I implemented the toy to use two cores on my machine.  It's not the most general, modular, extendable, effective, nor efficient, but it does demonstrate parallel processing.  Hopefully a Julia wizard will improve it.

Here's the Julia code I used:

```
addprocs(2)

@everywhere function ez_front(n::Int, ez::DArray, hy::DArray)
  ez_local=localpart(ez)
  hy_local=localpart(hy)
  ez_local[1]=sin(n/10)
  @simd for i=2:length(ez_local)
    @inbounds ez_local[i] += (hy_local[i] - hy_local[i-1])
  end
end

@everywhere function ez_back(ez::DArray, hy::DArray)
  ez_local=localpart(ez)
  hy_local=localpart(hy)
  index_boundary::Int = first(localindexes(hy)[1])-1
  ez_local[1] += (hy_local[1]-hy[index_boundary])
  @simd for i=2:length(ez_local)
    @inbounds ez_local[i] += (hy_local[i] - hy_local[i-1])
  end
end

@everywhere function hy_front(ez::DArray, hy::DArray)
  ez_local=localpart(ez)
  hy_local=localpart(hy)
  index_boundary = last(localindexes(ez)[1])+1
  @simd for i=1:(length(hy_local)-1)
    @inbounds hy_local[i] += (ez_local[i+1] - ez_local[i])
  end
  hy_local[end] += (ez[index_boundary] - ez_local[end])
end

@everywhere function hy_back(ez::DArray, hy::DArray)
  ez_local=localpart(ez)
  hy_local=localpart(hy)
  @simd for i=2:(length(hy_local)-1)
    @inbounds hy_local[i] += (ez_local[i+1] - ez_local[i])
  end
  hy_local[end] -= ez_local[end]
end


function fdtd1d_parallel(steps::Int, ie::Int = 200)
  ez = dzeros((ie,),workers()[1:2],2)
  hy = dzeros((ie,),workers()[1:2],2)
  for n = 1:steps
    @sync begin
      @async begin
        remotecall(workers()[1],ez_front,n,ez,hy)
        remotecall(workers()[2],ez_back,ez,hy)
      end
    end
    @sync begin
      @async begin
        remotecall(workers()[1],hy_front,ez,hy)
        remotecall(workers()[2],hy_back,ez,hy)
      end
    end
  end
  (convert(Array{Float64},ez), convert(Array{Float64},hy))
end

fdtd1d_parallel(1);
@time sol2=fdtd1d_parallel(10);
```

On my machine (an old 32-bit 2-core laptop), this parallel version wasn't faster than the local version until `ie` was set to somewhere around `5000000`.

This is an interesting case for learning parallel processing in Julia, but if I needed to solve Maxwell's equations using FDTD, I'd first consider the many FDTD software libraries that are already available.  Perhaps a Julia package could interface to one of those.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this code only works on v0.3, and the `@inbounds` has also sped up the code. After adding `@inbounds` to the unparallelized version, the parallelized code doesn't show its advantage unless I use a `steps` around `100`, I can't understand this behavior very well. Anyway, thanks for your effort!

Comment: Yeah, I'm usually at the HEAD of the Julia repo.  There is some overhead with parallelization (setup, message passing, etc.) and my machine only has one slow bus to memory that the core's have to share.

Comment: Though the answer is "not the most general, modular, extendable, effective, nor efficient", no one can ignore your effort, and, 千金市骨, so, +50 :D